# Deploying a Ruby Command Line Application that Depends on Non-Rubygems-Hosted Gems

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am attempting to deploy a small command-line application written in Ruby.  Many of the gems that the application depends on are hosted on my github account.  I have specified their locations in the `Gemfile` appropriately.  When I clone the repo on the deployment machine and run `bundle install` from the root, all goes smoothly.  I can then run the command line app (named "hippo") with `bin/hippo`.  I would like to install the app to the system so that I do not need to patch `$PATH` or specify the path to the executable in order to use it.

When I run `gem install /path/to/my/.gem/file`, installation fails and says that it cannot resolve the dependencies to my personal gems hosted on my Github account.  I gather this is because the `gem install` command does not read the `Gemfile`, only the `gemspec` (why on earth did the bundler people name their file `Gemfile` instead of `BundleFile` or something?), and the locations of the gems are specified in the `Gemfile` (there is no way to point to a github gem in a gemspec, right?).  I have the same issue when I use the `rake install` task that comes with a bundle-scaffolded gem.  However, when I run `bundle exec gem install /path/to/my/gemfile` then it installs OK, I guess because it sees my gems on the bundler-altered load path and decides that they are already installed.  But then, when I try to run the executable, it fails because it can't find the dependencies when they are required.  (Note that the executable has `require bundler/setup` as its first line after the shebang).

So I ask: what is a good way to deploy, with bundler, a command line application that depends on non-rubygems-hosted gems?

Comment: Are you doing a Bundler.require after requiring bundler/setup?

Comment: @davidfurber Nope.  Is there a reason I would need to?  I require individual gems as needed throughout my code.

Comment: In that case none that I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

`bundle exec` sets up your load path correctly so that the gems are visible when you `require bundler/setup`. One option would be to always run your binary with `bundle exec bin/hippo`.

Something more suited to your purposes might be to run `bundle install --standalone`, which generates a `bundle/bundler/setup.rb` file within your project's directory. That file sets up load paths correctly for you, so you'd just need to do something like `require_relative '../bundle/bundler/setup'` from your binary instead of `require 'bundler/setup'`.